# how to add the reference to the content?

Tags: table-of-contents

Today ,I use the `\tableofcontents`to yield a content ,however ,it lacks of the reference .

My trial

```
     \documentclass{ctexart }
      \begin{document  }
        \addcontentsline{ toc }{ section }{Reference }
        \tableofcontents
      \end{ document }
```

Fortunately ,the reference appear to the first line ,while I need it appear on the last line.

so I wonder how to revise.thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the `thebibliography` you have to use

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}
```

inside the environment:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}
\bibitem{label} Insert here the reference data.
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: ,thanks,best solution .BTW,the content appear the `bibliography`,how to change  it to the chinese character "参考文献 "

Comment: Use `\renewcommand{\bibname}{foo}` on preamble.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the package `tocbibind` that automatically adds the bibliography to the ToC:

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

The option `nottoc` is to avoid adding the ToC itself to the ToC.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
   \begin{document}
      \tableofcontents
      \newpage
      I use the softwares
   \begin{thebibliography}{99}
       \bibitem{one}
         mathematica 8.0
       \bibitem{two}
        maple8.0
   \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]